# I got an error saying my function is missing the return value

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function which gives me a comparison between the density of two items, Item 3 and Item 1.

```
from typing import List

def func(list_items: List[Myclass]) -> bool:
        for item1 in list_items:
            if item1.name == 'Item 3':
                for item2 in list_items:
                    if item2.name == 'Item 1':
                        if item1.density > item2.density:
                            return True
                        else:
                            return False
```

I got an error:

```
Missing return statement mypy(error)
```

I don't why I got this error, someone could help me how to correct this function?

Comment: What if after executing the loop the code doesn't return anything? I mean there is no item `Item 3` or `Item 1`, then also the function need to return a value

Comment: @kuro my program would break, I don't know what to write

Comment: You need to ask yourself how you would want the function to behave if either 'Item 3" or 'Item 1' were not found in the list. Would returning False make sense. Should you perhaps raise an exception suggesting that your data are not in the format that you'd expected. One other thought, could there be more than one occurrence of either 'Item 1' or 'Item 3' in the list?

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that, for example, `list_items` could be empty? What do you think should happen in this case? What do you think *will* happen in this case? Now, test it. What *does* happen in this case? Do you see why Mypy complains? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to think logically about the flow of the code before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is equivalent to:

```py
from typing import List

def func(list_items: List[Myclass]) -> bool:
    for item1 in list_items:
        if item1.name == 'Item 3':
            for item2 in list_items:
                if item2.name == 'Item 1':
                    if item1.density > item2.density:
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False

    return None  # same as not writing a return statement
```

And `mypy` is saying that `return None`/"no return statement" does not match the declared `bool` return type.

Some example options you have:

1. make the last line return `True` or `False`
2. declare the function can sometimes return `None`, e.g. return type `bool | None` (or `Union[bool, None]` for older Python versions)
3. raise an exception, which will crash the program if unhandled by the caller

Note: to use `Union`, you'll need `from typing import Union`. Older Python versions that aren't *too* old can still use `bool | None` if you `from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: So do I still say bool in the type hint?

Comment: I got this error: def func(list_items: List[Myclass]) -> None | bool:
E   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'NoneType' and 'type'. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'NoneType' and 'type'

Comment: Oh, the `bool | None` is a newer syntax that's not as backwards compatible as the equivalent alternative: `Union[bool, None]` (you'll have to `from typing import Union`)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with an assumption of what [part of] your MyClass class looks like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name, density):
        self._name = name
        self._density = density
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @property
    def density(self):
        return self._density
```

Now, rather than have an outer and inner loop in your function, let's do this:

```
def getMyClass(list_: List[MyClass], name: str) -> MyClass:
    for c in list_:
        if name == c.name:
            return c
    return None

def func(list_: List[MyClass]) -> bool:
    if (item1 := getMyClass(list_, 'Item 1')) and (item3 := getMyClass(list_, 'Item 3')):
        return item1.density > item3.density
    return False
```

This structure will stop the linter complaints but doesn't necessarily manage how you'd want to handle a situation where either 'Item 1' or 'Item 3' were absent. If that were to happen, the function would return False which may not be what you want